# Access database - Form

Tags: database, windows, forms, ms-access

Simply I would like one form to open on top of another (automatically).I've searched the net and found nothing that helps or works.

In some more details - When opening the database, the system automatically loads up "Form1", which looks very nice in the middle of not only my screen, but others as well, but I would like to hide all the visible sign's of access. Yes I can hide the tool bars etc, but what I was looking for was to create a form "Background", load that automatically and then load up "Form1" on top.

For some reason I can't seem to get form1 to load so it's visible. Yes it loads, but under the background form. I've tried all settings of popup, modal, visible, onload, onopen. I've set the database to open minimized (but that does not hide the fact that it is access).

Please can anyone come up with a solution.

Comment: are you asking to hide the MS Access window? its not entirely not possible but complex code needed to make the form invisible/transparent, custom form on top of it and so on.. not worth it.

Comment: @krish - I am trying to hide the MS Access window. I've changed the splash screen and along with a special tool bar, removal of the status bar and hiding the tables/queries it just trying to get one form on top of another. It is worth it as my database looks just about like a program (which is how my boss wants it to look, he knows its a database, but wants the other employee's to see a program which can't be messed with.

Comment: the keyword is "which can't be messed with" you should be reading more about Access Security level rather than falsely illustrating its a win application :) anyway one way would be having one form without caption bar, on open > fill the monitor with this form and closing this form will quit the application. but you will then miss all Access ribbon futures.

Comment: @krish - Thats exactly what I need  (the fill the monitor bit). I created that, but I want my text boxes etc to be in the middle of the screen and the best way I could find would be to create the "background" to fill the background and then form1 (a small form) could be centered as per each computer thats running the database.

Comment: use the anchoring method to anchor your components. or use form resize event to calculate the margins. if you only going to have one form why not simply develop in another application?

Comment: @krish - I've got multiple forms of varying size. I was going to use Visual Studio, but thought I'd start by creating the database, then move onto that if I had time. 

Can you explain how to calculate the margins so any form I show can have the objects in the middle of the screen

Answer (score 0):

Just to clear things up:

You want a hidden form (background) that loads another form that is visible?
All this needs to be done in a windows form application (c#)?

Is this what you want?

You could try VBA.
This is how a form is loaded.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load() 
  OpenForm(FormName, View, FilterName, WhereCondition, DataMode, WindowMode, OpenArgs)
End Sub
```

I don't have access to ms-Access now, but I believe this should work.

These are parameters you should/can fill in:
FormName, View, FilterName, WhereCondition, DataMode, WindowMode & OpenArgs

More info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff820845.aspx

Comment: No. Its within MS-Access. When the database loads, no forms are loaded. I want 2 forms to load. Firstly "background" then "form1" (a small delay is acceptable)

Comment: Tried doCmd.open form etc. It opens it but places it behind the background form. I need it on top

Comment: Try setting the windowMode to acDialog.

Comment: Now it opens up form1, but not the background. When I close form1 it then opens up the background form.  AAAGGGHHHHH. This is doing my head in :) p.s. thanks for all your help so far.

Comment: You're welcome. I will google a bit more and if I find more, I will let you know!